# Regex: Check if string contains SSN in any part of the string

Tags: javascript, regex

Can any one tell how to check if a String contains a social security number (SSN) using REGEX

Example data:

(1): `my ssn is 123-44-8686`

validate this ==> Need to return as true, since it contains a number in SSN format (XXX-XX-XXXX)

(2) `my ssn is nothing` ==> Need to return as false, since it does not contain a number in SSN format

Comment: what do you mean by ssn format?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Or are you looking for Stack Overflow users to provide you with something you can copy & paste?

Comment: SSN of what country??

Comment: Let's see, you could google "regexp ssn", and the first result gives you what you need. Or, you could read the first page of any regexp tutorial and discover that you need the regexp `/\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d\d\d/`. Where exactly were you getting stuck? I'm curious how you plan to become a programmer if you don't know how to google or how to read a simple tutorial.

Comment: I had to delete my answer because of a unnecessary downvote! If someone plans to downvote, they should at least have the courtesy to explain why. The answer I provided does work and I would love to know as to why it is criticized.

Answer (score -1):

No need to use REGEX.
 Hopefully Something like this will work

```
var str = "123-44-8686";  
var res = str.split("-");  
if(res.length == 3){  
  var ssn1=res[0];  
  if(ssn1.length==3){  
    var ssn2=res[1];  
    if(ssn2.length==2){  
      var ssn3=res[2];  
      if(ssn3.length==4){  
        alert("valid formate");
      }
    }
  }
}
else{
alert('Invalid formate');
}
```